# Intento subir archivos al servidor asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, asp

necesito su ayuda estoy empezando con asp .net mvc, necesito subir archivos al servidor, este es mi html:

```
<form action="javascripts:;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn-send-ajax" value="Enviar" />
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="btn-send-ajax" href="#" onclick="EditPost();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Exportar"> <i class="dx-icon-save"></i></a>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn-send-ajax").click(function () {


       var selectFile = ($("#fileUpload"))[0].files[0];

        var dataString = new FormData();

        if (!selectFile) {
            alert("No se ha Cargado El Archivo (html)");
        }


        dataString.append("fileUpload", selectFile);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadFileView","Home")',
            type: "Post",
            data: dataString,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async:false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (typeof (data.value) != "undefined") {
                    alert(data.Message);
                } else {
                    alert("Error No identificado");
                }
            },

            error: function (data) {

            }

        });
    });
});
```

este es mi controlador:

```
 public ActionResult LoadFileView(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload) {
        try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            fileUpload.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Value = false, Message = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { Value = true, Message = "Subido Con Exito" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

todo funciona bien, llega hasta el controlador, se ejecuta la linea:

```
 return Json(new { Value = true, Message = "Subido Con Exito" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

pero en la vista me muestra el mensaje: "Error No identificado"
me llega a crear la carpeta pero no el archivo.
Necesito una Mano, porfavor...

Comment: Considera que ese `LoadFileView` debe tener el atributo HttpPost

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la la sentencia **`if`**, más precisamente en la comparación 

`if (typeof (data.value) != "undefined")`.

`undefined` es una palabra registrada de javascript por lo cual no debería llevar comillas, sino lo interpreta como un **`String`**

Comment: gracias lucas...

Answer (score 0):

ya funciona, el primer cambio es que

```
 if (typeof (data.Value) != "undefined")
```

y otra cosa mas es en el controlador, estaba armando mal la ruta:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadFileView(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload) {
        try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
            fileUpload.SaveAs(path + Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.FileName));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Value = false, Message = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { Value = true, Message = "Subido Con Exito" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```